# Will @Cacheable speed up application using a shared database?

Tags: database, spring, caching, ehcache

I am writing a server-side application, say `app1`, using Spring-boot. This `app1` accesses a database `db1` on a dedicated DB server. To speed up DB access, I have marked some of my JPARepository as `@Cacheable(<some_cache_key)`, with an expiration time, say 1 hour.

The problem is: `db1` is **shared among several applications**, each may update entries inside it.

***Question***: will I have performance gain in my `app1` by using caches inside my application (`@Cacheable`)? (Note, the cache is inside my application, not inside the database, i.e. mask the entire DB with cache manager like Redis)

Here are my thoughts:

1. If another application `app2` modifies a DB entry, how would the cache inside `app1` know that entry is updated? Then my `app1`'s cache went stale, isn't it? (until it starts to refresh after the fixed 1hr refresh cycle)
2. if #1 is correct, then does it mean the correct way of setting up cache should be **mask the entire DB** with some sort of cache manager. Is Redis for such kind of usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, many questions there.

> Will I have performance gain in my app1 by using caches inside my
>   application (@Cacheable)?

You should always benchmark it but theoretically, it will be faster to access the cache than the database

> If another application app2 modifies a DB entry, how would the cache
>   inside app1 know that entry is updated? Then my app1's cache went
>   stale, isn't it? (until it starts to refresh after the fixed 1hr
>   refresh cycle)

It won't be updated unless you are using a clustered cache. Ehcache using a Terracotta cluster is such a cache. But yes, if you stick on a basic application cache, it will get stale.

> if #1 is correct, then does it mean the correct way of setting up
>   cache should mask the entire DB with some sort of cache manager. Is
>   Redis for such kind of usage?

Now it gets subtle. I'm not a Redis expert. But as far as I know, Redis is frequently used as a cache but it's actually a NoSQL database. And it won't be in front (again, from as far as I know), it will be aside. So you will first query Redis to see if your data is there and then your database. If your database is much slower to access and you have a really good cache hit, it will improve your performance. But please do a benchmark.

Real caches (like Ehcache) are a bit more efficient. They add the concept of near caching. So your app will keep cache entries in memory but also on the cache server. If the entry is updated, near cache will be updated. So you get application cache performance but also coherence between servers.

Comment: I check the cluster cache concept out: http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.1/clustered-cache.html . So, looks like I should put up cache inside all applications (and should report to the same cache cluster manager) using the same DB in order to avoid stale cache.